# java.io.File vs java.nio.Files which is the preferred in new code?

Tags: java, file, io, nio, java-io

While writing answers around SO, a user tried pointing out that `java.io.File` should not be used in new code, instead he argues that the the *new* object `java.nio.Files` should be used instead; he linked to [this article](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks).

Now I have been developing in Java for several years now, and have not heard this argument before; since reading his post I have been searching, and have not found many other sources that confirm this, and personally, I feel like many of the points argued in the article are weak and that if you know how to read them, errors thrown by the *File* class will generally tell you exactly what the issue is.

As I am continually developing new code my question is this:

Is this an active argument in the Java community? Is [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) preferred over [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) for new code? What are the major advantages / disadvantages between the two?

Comment: One good reason is the utilization of streams for file operations for eg: reading a list of files as a stream rather than an arraylist

Comment: In case of NIO, Memory Mapped Buffers allow mapping a file directly from the file system (without loading into memory). It would be possible to handle very large files without running out of heap space.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) that you linked give the answer:

> The java.nio.file package defines interfaces and classes for the Java
>   virtual machine to access files, file attributes, and file systems.
>   This API may be used to overcome many of the limitations of the
>   java.io.File class. The toPath method may be used to obtain a Path
>   that uses the abstract path represented by a File object to locate a
>   file. The resulting Path may be used with the Files class to provide
>   more efficient and extensive access to additional file operations,
>   file attributes, and I/O exceptions to help diagnose errors when an
>   operation on a file fails.

Answer (score 15):

`File` has a newer implementation: `Path`. With a builder `Paths.get("...")`. And `Files` has many nice utility functions with better implementations too (`move` instead of the sometimes failing `File.renameTo`).

A `Path` maintains its file system. Hence you can copy out of a zip file system ("jar:file:..... .zip") some path to another file system and vice versa.

`File.toPath()` may help an incremental transition.

The utilities alone in `Files` make a move to the newer classes profitable.